# Can the string formatter be parametrized with variables?

Tags: c#, .net, string, string-formatting

#### Example

Here is an example:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Test {0, 10}", 1100);
        Console.WriteLine("Test {0, 10}", 2);
        Console.WriteLine("Test {0, 10}", 40);
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
Test       1100
Test          2
Test         40
Press any key to continue . . .
```

#### Question

Is it possible to make the number `10` in the above example variable?

The following depicts the intention, but does not compile because a `string` is expected, not an `int`:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int i = 10;
        Console.WriteLine("Test {0, i}", 1100);
        Console.WriteLine("Test {0, i}", 2);
        Console.WriteLine("Test {0, i}", 40);
    }
}
```

Comment: what about string concartenation?

`Console.WriteLine("Test {0, " + i + "}", 1100);`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With C# 6 you can use [string interpolation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn961160.aspx):

```
Console.WriteLine($"Test {{0, {i}}}", 1100);
Console.WriteLine($"Test {{0, {i}}}", 2);
Console.WriteLine($"Test {{0, {i}}}", 40);
```

The benefit of string interpolation in C# 6 is that it includes compile-time checking of variables. In order to make string interpolation work you need to prefix your string with a dollar sign (`$`).

Another option without string interpolation would be this:

```
int i = 10;
Console.WriteLine("Test {0, " + i + "}", 1100);
Console.WriteLine("Test {0, " + i + "}", 2);
Console.WriteLine("Test {0, " + i + "}", 40);
```

Or:

```
Console.WriteLine("Test " + 1100.ToString().PadLeft(i));
Console.WriteLine("Test " + 2.ToString().PadLeft(i));
Console.WriteLine("Test " + 40.ToString().PadLeft(i));
```

Comment: That's not what he askes for

Comment: So what is wrong with my answer? Care to explain what I did wrong?

Comment: It was wrong before you edited it which was the same time as the comment left by @disklosr

Comment: My comment was for your first version of your response which was not answering op's question. I removed the -1 after your edit

Answer (score 3):

A simple solution would be:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int i = 10;
        Console.WriteLine("Test {0, " + i + "}", 1100);
        Console.WriteLine("Test {0, " + i + "}", 2);
        Console.WriteLine("Test {0, " + i + "}", 40);
    }
}
```